# WebClient testing

Tags: java, spring, webclient

Everthing works fine until I define `WebClient` inside `UsersController`

```
@RestController
public class UsersController {

    private WebClient webClient;

    public UsersController(WebClient webClient) {
        this.webClient = webClient;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public void basicController() {
        System.out.println("Controller ");
    }
}

public interface MyService {
    double someService(double d);
}

@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    @Override
    public double someService(double d) {
        System.out.println("Service");
        return d;
    }

}

@SpringBootTest
//@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
//@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
//@WebFluxTest(UsersController.class)
public class UsersControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    UsersController usersController;

    @Autowired
    MyService myService;

    @Test
    public void testController() {
        usersController.basicController();
    }
    @Test
    public void testService() {
        myService.someService(1);
    }

}
```

I am trying to consume restApi and it's working fine if this approach is used

```java
private WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("https://someUri");
UsersController usersController = new UsersController(webClient);
```

How can I be more flexible and include service layer into this?
Using the above code ends up with :

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Comment: And your problem is?